# Does Re-Tail force you to leave at closing time?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In previous entries to the *Animal Crossing* series, the main shop in the village (some variation of Tom Nook's shop) responded to closing time.  The music would change very near to closing time (~5 minutes to close) and Nook would eventually ask you to leave.

Does anything like this happen in Re-Tail in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?  This question may seem trivial if you aren't familiar with Animal Crossing, but the answer to this question is a change from the series status-quo that could save evening players a lot of grief. I happened to have this question, was able to find the answer by trying it myself, and posted it here in hopes that it would help others with the same question.

Comment: It's actually less important to reach the store before closing in _AC:NL_ since you can keep bugs/fish in your home storage now. This makes evening/night play _much_ more forgiving. (I'm not the downvoter though, this is a fine question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My village's "Re-Tail" closes at 11pm, so I went to visit tonight near closing time.  Aside from another villager being present at closing time, nothing out of the ordinary happened. I continued waiting for a few minutes...

[image]

...and was not asked to leave.  So if you have any business to conduct at Re-Tail, so long as you get in the door before closing time, you'll have plenty of time to take care of things.  If the developers created any special events for when Re-Tail closes at night, it is not obvious or within the same time interval as previous AC games.

As a point of note, the lights were out and the shop was closed upon my exit.

Comment: Works the same for me at 2AM.

Comment: best I can tell, *all* stores let you stay until you leave.